# Error message for undeclared variable on Arduino, using typedef

Tags: c, arduino, typedef, fuzzy-logic

I have created a fuzzy control system on an arduino with a MATLAB file and a free online conversion tool. However when i try to run it I get an error I can't fix:

> '_FIS_ARR_OP' has not been declared

I know what a typedef is, but I do not exactly understand how it is used here with the double paranthesis...

```
Header file
//***********************************************************************
#define FIS_TYPE float
#define FIS_RESOLUSION 101
#define FIS_MIN -3.4028235E+38
#define FIS_MAX 3.4028235E+38
typedef FIS_TYPE(*_FIS_MF)(FIS_TYPE, FIS_TYPE*);
typedef FIS_TYPE(*_FIS_ARR_OP)(FIS_TYPE, FIS_TYPE);
typedef FIS_TYPE(*_FIS_ARR)(FIS_TYPE*, int, _FIS_ARR_OP);

//***********************************************************************
```

Declaration of function where _FIS_ARR_OP is used:

```
FIS_TYPE fis_array_operation(FIS_TYPE *array, int size, _FIS_ARR_OP pfnOp)
{
    int i;
    FIS_TYPE ret = 0;

    if (size == 0) return ret;
    if (size == 1) return array[0];

    ret = array[0];
    for (i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        ret = (*pfnOp)(ret, array[i]);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Use of the function:

```
FIS_TYPE fis_MF_out(FIS_TYPE** fuzzyRuleSet, FIS_TYPE x, int o)
{
    FIS_TYPE mfOut;
    int r;

    for (r = 0; r < fis_gcR; ++r)
    {
        int index = fis_gRO[r][o];
        if (index > 0)
        {
            index = index - 1;
            mfOut = (fis_gMF[fis_gMFO[o][index]])(x, fis_gMFOCoeff[o][index]);
        }
        else if (index < 0)
        {
            index = -index - 1;
            mfOut = 1 - (fis_gMF[fis_gMFO[o][index]])(x, fis_gMFOCoeff[o][index]);
        }
        else
        {
            mfOut = 0;
        }

        fuzzyRuleSet[0][r] = fis_min(mfOut, fuzzyRuleSet[1][r]);
    }
    return fis_array_operation(fuzzyRuleSet[0], fis_gcR, fis_max);
}
```

Comment: Consider putting together a [mcve] so we can see the whole picture. You might find you can't duplicate the issue in a small example and that might lead you to an answer

Comment: There are actually microcontrollers with fuzzy logic instruction set support, for example Freescale HCS12. You'll have to be handy with Motorola assembler though. But the end product is going to run around in circles around the sluggish Arduino.

Comment: Stupid question... did you include the header file?

Answer (score 0):

This `typedef` is creating a type alias for a function pointer.

```
typedef FIS_TYPE(*_FIS_ARR_OP)(FIS_TYPE, FIS_TYPE);
```

defines `_FIS_ARR_OP` as a pointer to a function returning a `FIS_TYPE`, and which accepts arguments of types (in order) `FIS_TYPE` and `FIS_TYPE`.

The first set of parentheses are around the new type name and the `*` making it a pointer. The second set are like what you see in a function declaration, containing a list of the types of the variables that the function accepts.

---

In both C and C++, I don't encounter any errors. Is your header file included in *all* of the source files where you use the types defined?

Answer (score 0):

I compiled your code on Visual Studio C and don't get any errors.

Note that leading underscores are reserved for the compiler, so consider removing the leading underscores.